# Getting the running jobs on an LSF cluster using python and PlatformLSF

Tags: python, lsf

I'm trying to write a simple task manager in python that will be used to run a large number of jobs in an LSF cluster.  I'm stuck trying to determine (within a python script) the number of running jobs for a given user.  On the command line this would come from the command `bjobs`.

IBM [makes available](https://github.com/PlatformLSF/platform-python-lsf-api) a python wrapper to the LSF C API.  Working with [one of their examples](https://github.com/PlatformLSF/platform-python-lsf-api/blob/master/examples/job_submit.py) and [some documentation](https://www.bsc.es/support/LSF/9.1.2/api_ref/lsb_userinfo.html) from a copy of the C API that I found online, I have been able to cobble together the following script.

```py
from pythonlsf import lsf
lsf.lsb_init("test")
userArr = lsf.new_stringArray(1)
lsf.stringArray_setitem(userArr, 0, 'my_username')
intp_num_users = lsf.new_intp()
lsf.intp_assign(intp_num_users, 1)
user_info = lsf.lsb_userinfo(userArr,intp_num_users)
```

The variable `user_info` has attributes `'numPEND'`, `'numRESERVE'`, `'numRUN'`, and `'numStartJobs'`, but all of these are 0.  They remain zero even when `bjobs` reports a running job.

Can anyone tell what I might be doing wrong in the code snippet above?  I've read through both the C and python documentation several times, but can't find an error.